# Nutch 2.3.1 and Solr 6 error while indexing

Tags: indexing, solr, nutch

I'm getting this error when I try to index:

> IndexingJob: starting
>       SolrIndexerJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar, jobid=job_local1960263394_0001
>           at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
>           at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:154)
>           at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:176)
>           at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:202)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:211)

Comment: Trying out on windows? Also what error do you see in hadoop.log file?

Comment: Can you check your hadoop.log file and share with us?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this to solve this problem

```
sudo -E -----Your Command --------
```